# GIT issue after Yosemite update

Tags: git, osx-yosemite

I updated my OSX last night to Yosemite. Now anytime I try to run GIT in the terminal I get a pop-up saying; "The git command requires the command line developer tools."

Anybody know how to get around this ? I already have GIT installed and a repo initialized.

Comment: What is your `$PATH` variable's contents?

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/michaelvilla/Documents/coreHaskell/:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Applications/Android/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Applications/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools

Answer (score 0):

Try: `xcode-select --install` from the command line.  Seems like your git install needs the XCode command like tools.  (If you get a permission error, try with sudo: `sudo xcode-select --install`.

Answer (score 0):

Right, got it working.

If you update to Yosemite as far as I can tell you will need to install Command Line Tools again. If you type git into the terminal as mentioned in the question a popup will appear. It'll either ask you to install xcode or just the CLT. I installed the CLT and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29580031/2323713 - A manual download and install of a new CLT version solved this issue for me.