# Error installing/bundling gem unf_ext -v '0.0.6'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I'm trying to bundle intall `unf_ext -v '0.0.6'` but I keep getting this error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling unf.cc
In file included from unf.cc:1:
In file included from ./unf/normalizer.hh:4:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:265:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:15:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:628:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:604:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:341:10: fatal error: '__debug' file not found
#include <__debug>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [unf.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

I've run `gem update --system` and i've `brew install coreutils` but I'm still getting the same error.

**Update: Answer**
Downloaded and installed `commandlinetoolsosx10.10forxcode6.2.dmg` from [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#).  No need to uninstall anything.

Comment: Corinne, I believe you are using Mac OSX. 'Failed to build gem native extension.' error is usually caused due to missing command line tools for Xcode. Do you have them installed? If not, install them from Xcode-> Preferences-> Downloads, or from the command line with xcode-select --install and retry your gem installation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bug in the new xcode tools. It broke eventmachine in my case. See [Missing C++ header <__debug> after updating OSX Command Line Tools 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529455/missing-c-header-debug-after-updating-osx-command-line-tools-6-3) for answers with dummy files and reinstallation links. I downgraded to 6.2 and the problem went away.

Answer (score 8):

Doing this worked for me:

```
echo '#define _LIBCPP_ASSERT(x, m) ((void)0)' | sudo tee -a /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__debug > /dev/null
```

Then run `bundle` again.

And, since this is only meant to be a temporary fix until Apple releases a patch, remove that newly created file with:

```
sudo rm /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__debug
```