# rails gem unf_ext will not install when bundling with stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

Stack/ Tech specs:
ruby 2.2.2
rails 4.2.3

Using OS X 10.11

I am attempting to install stripe in my rails app. Added `gem 'stripe'` to my Gemfile, ran bundle install, and received this error message:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151006-77029-11oqg9a.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-static-libstdc++
--without-static-libstdc++
--with-stdc++lib
--without-stdc++lib
/Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:735:in `try_func'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:966:in `block in have_library'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
from /Users/t/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:961:in `have_library'
from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Searched for known issues and found [Gem unf_ext failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602463/gem-unf-ext-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension), but this appears to be related to an older version & an older version of xcode.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have solved this issue. After upgrading OS X I was required to re-agree to the terms & conditions in X-Code. After completing the agreement process I am able to run bundle install without errors.