# Unable to install therubyracer on clean install of Yosemite and clean version of ruby

Tags: osx-yosemite, therubyracer

There are many people with similar issues and I've been one of them in the past on other machines and none of the solutions out there appear to work -- I also appear to have different error than others who have similar problems:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150412-25981-y7cvt6.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling accessor.cc
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
In file included from accessor.cc:1:
In file included from ./rr.h:6:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:265:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:15:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:628:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:604:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:341:10: fatal error: '__debug' file not found
#include <__debug>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [accessor.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ecnalyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@canopy/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ecnalyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@canopy/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.0.0/therubyracer-0.12.2/gem_make.out
```

When running:

```
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.2'
```

or simply

```
bundle install
```

with `therubyracer` included in my gemfile.

I'm running Yosemite 10.10.3, Ruby 2.0.0-p353, I have uninstalled everything and tried the `gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8` solution that comes up frequently with these kind of problems, but have found no resolution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to solve this by re-installing [Command Line Tools for XCode 6.2](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (instead of those for XCode 6.3).

There's more discussion in [Stack Overflow 29529455](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529455/missing-c-header-debug-after-updating-osx-command-line-tools-6-3).

Comment: You don't need to, at least I didn't.

Answer (score 11):

Creating a temporary file '__debug' solved this issue for me.

Run this command in terminal:

echo '#define _LIBCPP_ASSERT(x, m) ((void)0)' | sudo tee -a /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__debug > /dev/null