# Bundle Install will not update eventmachine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to clone a repository from Github and I am on the step where I run "bundle install". However everytime I try to run this I get the following message:

```
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run "gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'" I get

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/christinating/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from binder.cpp:20:
In file included from ./project.h:29:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:439:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:628:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:604:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:341:10: fatal error: '__debug' file not found
#include <__debug>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/christinating/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/christinating/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/eventmachine-1.0.3/gem_make.out
```

I have tried a number of solutions (that have not worked) that I found online:

1. I've changed my ruby version to 2.1.5 in my .ruby-version file and gemfile.
2. I have also changed the eventmachine version in my gemfile.lock and gemfile to 1.0.4 and then also 1.0.7. After each change I then tried to run bundle install or gem install eventmachine. Which just produced the following:

Fetching: eventmachine-1.0.7.gem (100%)
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
        /Users/christinating/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
    checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
    checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
    checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
    checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
    checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
    checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
    checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
    checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
    checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
    checking for rb_time_new()... yes
    checking for sys/event.h... yes
    checking for sys/queue.h... yes
    checking for clock_gettime()... no
    checking for gethrtime()... no
    creating Makefile

    make "DESTDIR=" clean

    make "DESTDIR="
    compiling binder.cpp
    In file included from binder.cpp:20:
    In file included from ./project.h:29:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:439:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:628:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:604:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:341:10: fatal error: '__debug' file not found
    #include <__debug>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

    make failed, exit code 2

    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/christinating/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/christinating/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/eventmachine-1.0.7/gem_make.out
    Christinas-iMac:scholarhood christinating$ gem install eventmachine
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/christinating/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
    checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
    checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
    checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
    checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
    checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
    checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
    checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
    checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
    checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
    checking for rb_time_new()... yes
    checking for sys/event.h... yes
    checking for sys/queue.h... yes
    checking for clock_gettime()... no
    checking for gethrtime()... no
    creating Makefile

    make "DESTDIR=" clean

    make "DESTDIR="
    compiling binder.cpp
    In file included from binder.cpp:20:
    In file included from ./project.h:29:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:439:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:628:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:604:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:341:10: fatal error: '__debug' file not found
    #include <__debug>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

    make failed, exit code 2

    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/christinating/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/christinating/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/eventmachine-1.0.7/gem_make.out
```

I'm really out of ideas and really need some help please!!!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361958/eventmachine-gem-install-fail]

Comment: I am on a Mac I don't think those instructions work for me??

Comment: This is the root cause of the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529455/missing-c-header-debug-after-updating-osx-command-line-tools-6-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happened was that I didn't have xcode installed! once I downloaded I was able to run bundle install and update eventmachine

Comment: It must have been some library that was bundled with xcode. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: No need to install the Xcode, just make sure that you have installed the latest Xcode command-line tools.