# thoughtbot Suspenders gem - 'bundle install' fails with capybara-webkit even after installing Qt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qt, installation, rubygems

I'm trying to use the Suspenders gem by ThoughtBot to start out a personal project and ran into an error with capybara-webkit when running `bundle install`. Google turned up a few similar reports and most seemed to be solved by installing Qt per the instructions at the capybara-webkit GitHub [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit) (I noticed the instructions are for OSX 10.9 Mavericks and 10.8 Mountain Lion, whereas I'm using 10.10 Yosemite, but I don't see anything for 10.10 specifically).

> If you get an error when building, along the lines of fatal error:
>   QObject: No such file or directory, you might be attempting the build
>   against Qt3, or an earlier version of Qt4. Make sure that the qmake in
>   your PATH links to Qt4.8.
>
> ```
> which qmake # to see where it links
> rm `which qmake` # IF it is linking to an old version
> ```

Instructions for OSX are:

> Go to the QT website (general downloads site, 4.8.6 installers) and
>   download Qt libraries 4.8.6 for Mac (185 MB) and debug libraries (480
>   MB).

So I downloaded and installed the two Qt libraries at the link. I get the following output from my command line:

```
Davids-MBP:app david$ which qmake
/usr/bin/qmake
Davids-MBP:app david$ qmake --version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /Library/Frameworks
```

However, when I run `bundle install` from within my app, I get this output:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150414-16090-1y906xu.rb extconf.rb 
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '/Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.0/src/webkit_server.pbproj'
make: *** No rule to make target `qmake'.  Stop.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-gl-dir
    --without-gl-dir
    --with-gl-include
    --without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
    --with-gl-lib
    --without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'make qmake' failed

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/capybara-webkit-1.5.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I went back and removed Qt, then tried building it from source per the linked doc. That process errored out like so:

```
Davids-MBP:app david$ brew install qt --build-from-source
==> Downloading https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.6/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DomT4/scripts/440e3cafde5bf6ec6f50cd28fa5bf89c280f1b53/Homebrew_R
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file src/gui/dialogs/qcolordialog_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/dialogs/qfiledialog_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/dialogs/qfontdialog_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/kernel/qapplication_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/kernel/qcocoaapplication_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/kernel/qcocoaapplicationdelegate_mac.mm
Hunk #4 succeeded at 295 (offset -13 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 342 (offset -13 lines).
patching file src/gui/kernel/qcocoaapplicationdelegate_mac_p.h
patching file src/gui/kernel/qcocoamenuloader_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/kernel/qcocoasharedwindowmethods_mac_p.h
patching file src/gui/kernel/qeventdispatcher_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/kernel/qt_cocoa_helpers_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/kernel/qwidget_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/styles/qmacstyle_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/util/qsystemtrayicon_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/widgets/qcocoamenu_mac.mm
patching file src/gui/widgets/qmenu_mac.mm
==> ./configure -prefix /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6 -system-zlib -qt-libtiff -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -confirm-license
==> make
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [.obj/release-shared/qglobal.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
make: *** [sub-corelib-make_default-ordered] Error 2
READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
```

Can anyone help?

I'm using ruby 2.2.1 through rbenv.

Answer (score 1):

Check the App Store to see if you recently updated to Command Line Tools 6.3.  If so, you'll need to install 6.3.1 which is now available on Apple's developer site: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#

Also, here's another StackOverflow issue that helped me solve this problem:
[Missing C++ header <__debug> after updating OSX Command Line Tools 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529455/missing-c-header-debug-after-updating-osx-command-line-tools-6-3)